# How to obtain the KEGG mudule based on KEGG KO? (KEGG mudule enrichment)

Tags: clustering, pathway, kegg

With [HUMAnN3](https://huttenhower.sph.harvard.edu/humann), I got the result of the KEGG KO annotation (by *humann_regroup_table*:humann_regroup_table --input hmp_subset_genefamilies.tsv --groups uniref90_ko --output hmp_subset_genefamilies_uniref90_ko.tsv).

I need to quantify/transform the KEGG KO annotation to KEGG module definitions.

However, I did not find the relevant guidance/instruction. Are there any relevant tutorials available for reference?

Just like the packages ("clusterProfiler") using R for transform to KEGG pathway (KEGG pathway enrichment analysis).

Thanks a lot!

Any help will get me out of trouble!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem with the question is it's not clear what "quantify/transform" KEGG really means. Nor is it clear what your background in coding or SQL is because this is a fairly simple operation. Sure I've done loads of this, but whether that transferable here its difficult to assess.

Comment: @M__  Thank you for replying. "quantify/transform" KEGG means that the result of the KEGG KO annotation (genome information) is mapped to KEGG modules for the functional annotation like "KEGG Pathway Enrichment Analysis" (by R package: clusterProfiler). I'm just starting to learn these. Can you give me some advice? Thanks a lot.